# How can I prevent sentences from being divided into several lines in the csv?

Tags: python, scrapy

I would like to collect the Japanese articles searched by google with scrapy.

I try to extract Japanese sentences.
In order to prevent sentences from being divided into several lines in the csv file, we decided to remove all newlines that represent the end of the line
then I run the following code to extracted sentences.

```
 text = text.replace('\n', '').replace('\t', '').replace(' ', '').replace(u'\n', '').replace(u'\t', '').replace(u' ', '')
 text = text.encode('utf-8')

 with open('out.csv', 'a') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter= ',' ,lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerow([text, response.url])
```

However, as I looked at the output csv, the sentences are still divided into several lines.
How can I prevent sentences from being split?
Also, I want to remove the line breaks to prevent sentences from being divided, but I do not want to remove the line breaks in the sentences.
Take that into account, I would like you to tell me how to divide the sentences into few lines

Comment: please, show us the sample output (csv file) ?

Comment: also print sample text lines

Comment: http://xfs.jp/hnKmcs
the csv is here (has many Japanese sentences)

Comment: http://xfs.jp/2hQWJB this is the problem part